# Load Facebook comment after click on show comments

Tags: javascript, facebook

I use Facebook comments plugin in my application. When page is visited, it slows down page load by some.

How can I add a **button** called *Show comments* and **only** after click on button `render` Facebook comments plugin.

[Here is a example](http://diply.com/dip/article/hollywood-transformations-that-will-leave-you-speechless)

This is what I have so far

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-numposts="5"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=<APP_ID>";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


</script>
```

Comment: You should include code demonstrating what you've tried so far, otherwise users may downvote the post because it seems you're asking them to do the coding for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom function

```
<button onClick="showComments();">show comments</button>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-numposts="5"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  function showComments() { // Custom function called on click
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=<APP_ID>";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one question. I have also facebook share button on same page. Would this my share button to not work until the facebook sdk is loaded?

Comment: If you want to get this working with `share` button one easy work-around could be using this together with `HTML` facebook share button like this one: `<a class="l q o" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<URL>" target="_blank" title="Facebook Share">Facebook</a>`. You may add custom styling to the button. Other solution could be to simply hide the comments `div` and show it on click of a button. Both should work theoretically by I haven't tried.